# My question was marked as duplicate but it's really not

Tags: discussion, exact-duplicates

I recently asked [this question](https://superuser.com/q/1589421/233470) about a strange behaviour my computer was having. It had recorded keystrokes I've made one month ago, leading to think about a possible malware/keylogger infection.

It has been marked as duplicate of [this one](https://superuser.com/q/1589421/233470), "How can I remove malicious spyware[...] of my PC?".

It's really not the same thing:

- I never asked how to remove malware. What I wanted to know was "what is causing that?".
- At the end it wasn't a malware at all, but a keyboard macro I accidentally created and launched.

I edited the question title and content to be more specific, and remove the mention about the mouse movements (because it was not the case; the menus were probably opened by some keyboard keys sent by the macro).

Could my question be reopened? I think it could be interesting for others.

Comment: If you edited the question it will have gone into the reopen queue, where users with the required privilege can vote to reopen or leave closed.

Comment: I would provide some substantial amount of information to your question.  Just saying it's not a duplicate isn't a good enough reason to not be a duplicate.  **If it's just about the question be closed, mention you suspect a hardware problem, and indicate you have a Logitech keyboard.**  I will let other users reopen the question, since the problem is solved, and won't actually ever be deleted by a community user due to the upvotes the answer received.  Since the problem is solved, and was caused by human error (hitting a macro key), benefit to the community is limited (in my opinion).

Comment: You currently have 3 re-open votes